# MySQL 8.0.31 replications fails when running in docker container?

Tags: mysql, replication, docker

Since a couple of days I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to start a replication between two MySQL 8.0.31 running each in a docker on a custom port. This always fails with ([Original Post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320319/mysql-replication-fails-with-permission-error-for-unknown-reason)):

```
Last_IO_Errno: 2003
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicator@xx.xx.xx.xx:33060' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx:33060' (110)
```

On my host is also an unused MariaDB running. So I made the same replication setup as used for the MySQL and this runs like a charm.

Now I'm wondering if MySQL has an issue when it runs in a docker? Is somebody here who is running the official MySQL docker image in a replication environment?

I urgently need to get this thing up and running and would be grateful for any help!

Comment: As far as I know this error occurs for the following scenarios. 1. firewall (servers doesn't communicate with each other). 2. bind-address on MySQL configuration. 3. The mysql user (in your case replicator). 4. Sometimes some systems like [SELinux](https://serverfault.com/questions/529259/mysql-replication-over-ssh-last-io-errno-2003-error-connecting-to-master) doesn't allow MySQL running  on a non standard port .

Comment: @ErgestBasha (1) is working correctly (I also tried to switch it off) (2) no bind address defined (3) I made a copy & paste and tested the user with `mysql -u` and checked the `GRANTS` several times (4) it's running on Ubuntu 20 - meanwhile I could find out that it works from Server2 -> Server1 but not from Server1 -> Server2. The strange thing is that both servers are identical (of course different IP) but they have an identical setup.

Comment: Does the MySQL error log  shows anything related to the issue?

Comment: unfortunately not. The log gives no helpful infos :-( I really have no idea. I did everything as written in the Original post (see link above) and I'm totally confused now that it works in one direction but not in the other one.

Comment: Maybe it is connected on the wrong database in which the user replicator isnt created?

Comment: I've tested this and it's the correct host and DB. The test was done by giving the `replicator` user all permissions and connect via `mysql -u replicator --host= --port= ...` If the DB or the post would not be correct, the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` would return much faster with an error (I tried it out :-) So it takes 60sec for the first return that the user cannot get access.

Comment: Have you tried restarting MySQL on the slave and doing stop slave, change master to..  start slave procedure again? By the way the replicator user isn't needed on the slave. Just for testing purpose could you allow bind address = 0.0.0.0 on the master side? Remove it after testing

Comment: I tried all this back and forth :-( I will try the bind address = 0.0.0.0 at first tomorrow morning. Why I don't need the replicator user on the slave? In the final step I'm trying to create a Master<->Master. Isn't it that each master is also a slave (depending on the direction of replication)? On one server1 I do `CHANGE MASTER TO server2...` and on the other server2 `CHANGE MASTER TO server1...` Or am I wrong?

Comment: I had master - slave on my mind . Late hours ...you need the user on both side

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm working on that issue since 3 days now...